# Calculate time difference between two EditText

Tags: android, date, time, timepicker

I have seen almost similar questions about this but my wont work as I want. Not at all in fact.

So I have been trying to calculate the time difference between two timestamps that I set with a TimePicker to two EditTexts.

Here is the code I dont get to work:

```
public void calcTime() throws Exception{
    String startTime = startworkFrom.getText().toString();
    String endTime = startworkTo.getText().toString();

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    Date time_1 = format.parse(startTime);
    Date time_2 = format.parse(endTime);

    long timeDiff = time_2.getTime() - time_1.getTime();

    System.out.println("Time difference" + timeDiff);
}
```

What is missing in the code?

**UPDATE**

I found the problem that is this line:

> DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

If I delete the '**a**'.
Also the value is really high. If I set 12:00 to 13:00 the difference should be 1.But I get a really huge value here. I will be using

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: What does getTime return?

Comment: @seanAshmore the getTime returns time in milliseconds. Maybe not so optimal

Answer (score 0):

> The only problem now is if I start to work late at night and then
>   stop working in the morning i will get a negative value but I guess
>   there is a fix for that for another topic.

This should do it

```
String neg = "-"; 
    long timeDiff;  
    if(timeDiff.contains(neg)){ 
    timeDiff = time_1.getTime() - time_2.getTime(); }
else{ timeDiff =
    time_2.getTime() - time_1.getTime(); }
    System.out.println("Time difference" + timeDiff);
```

Comment: Ok. I also saw now that getHour that I should be using is deprecated and it is the Calender method that's recommended to use I will change it I think

Comment: I have a **big** problem. When i calculate the time difference i get the hours right. But when the minutes get to 60 minutes the hour should add 1 hour. So this is not good.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the negative values is to use the Math library.
I did like this:

```
String a =""+Math.abs(diff/(60*60*1000)%24);
```